# Bad condition - Cubit

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

I'm trying to get to the RegistrationSendCode screen. But unfortunately I am getting a bad status error. Here is my provider and builder -
Provider -

```
class RegistrationSendCode extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return BlocProvider<RegistrationSendCodeCubit>(
      create: (context) => RegistrationSendCodeCubit(),
      child: RegistrationSendCodeBuilder(),
    );
  }
}
```

Builder -

```
class RegistrationSendCodeBuilder extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<RegistrationSendCodeCubit, RegistrationSendCodeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if(state is RegistrationSendCodeNotLoading) {
          RegistrationSendCodeWidget();
        } else if(state is RegistrationSendCodeLoading) {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),
          );
        } else if(state is RegistrationSendCodeLoaded) {
          return FullName();
        } else if(state is RegistrationSendCodeError) {
          return MyError();
        }
        throw StateError('err');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

error -

```
The following StateError was thrown building BlocBuilder<RegistrationSendCodeCubit, RegistrationSendCodeState>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<RegistrationSendCodeCubit?>], state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<RegistrationSendCodeCubit, RegistrationSendCodeState>#cd448):
Bad state: err

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BlocBuilder<RegistrationSendCodeCubit, RegistrationSendCodeState> BlocBuilder: return BlocProvider<RegistrationSendCodeCubit>(
```

It is expected that when I go to this screen, I should immediately get into the RegistrationSendCodeNotLoading state, which is logical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing the error, But you are not catching it anywhere

Try removing the line.

```
class RegistrationSendCodeBuilder extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<RegistrationSendCodeCubit, RegistrationSendCodeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if(state is RegistrationSendCodeNotLoading) {
           return RegistrationSendCodeWidget();   add return 
        } else if(state is RegistrationSendCodeLoading) {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),
          );
        } else if(state is RegistrationSendCodeLoaded) {
          return FullName();
        } else if(state is RegistrationSendCodeError) {
          return MyError();
        }
        throw StateError('err');  // ❌ remove this line
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If I remove this line, I get the following error - The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type. (Documentation) Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

Comment: Replace `throw StateError('err')` with  `return MyError();` You are good to go !

Comment: Um, now when I go to this screen, I immediately get into the MyError state. But, I have to get into the RegistrationSendCodeNotLoading state. Why can't I get into it?

Comment: I have an example, the previous screen, in which I just get into the Not Loading state. Here is an example https://dpaste.org/dFFiJ. And it works the way I need it, I get into the Not Loading state

Comment: You are not returning , try adding `return` statement infront of  `RegistrationSendCodeWidget();`, See my edited post

Answer (score 0):

`Builder` parameter must return a Widget to display for all states. In `RegistrationSendCodeNotLoading` state, you're not returning the widget.

It common approach to have `else` statement instead of `else if` for `RegistrationSendCodeError` state without exclusively checking it with condition.

Change code as below,

```dart
class RegistrationSendCodeBuilder extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<RegistrationSendCodeCubit, RegistrationSendCodeState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if(state is RegistrationSendCodeNotLoading) {
          return RegistrationSendCodeWidget();
        } else if(state is RegistrationSendCodeLoading) {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),
          );
        } else if(state is RegistrationSendCodeLoaded) {
          return FullName();
        } else {
          return MyError();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the error remains the same.

Comment: Error thrown because of this statement `throw StateError('err');`. Do you have it any where else?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question